# Any way to restrict disabling of secure boot?

Tags: boot, uefi, secure-boot

I have secure boot enabled and require signing of kernel modules before loading. The key used for signing is on an external drive to reduce chances of the key being compromised and being used to sign a malicious kernel module. Is there any way to prevent root from disabling secure boot via `mokutil --disable-validation`. An attacker could simply disable secure boot validation after shim loads, so the BIOS would have no idea, but unsigned kernel modules could load. This is what I am trying to mitigate or make more difficult.

Comment: If someone has obtained root access to your PC you're already compromised irrevocably and any protections in place become meaningless.

Comment: Isn't it possible to confine the root user using mandatory access controls like selinux?

Comment: Secure boot does not protect against an attacker that has physical access to the machine. You need physical access to disable secure boot in the way you describe. If you can't prevent physical access by untrusted users, I suggest setting a BIOS password to prevent unauthorized reboots.

Comment: @JohanMyréen "An attacker could simply disable secure boot validation after shim loads, so the BIOS would have no idea, but unsigned kernel modules could load", this is possible via `mokutil --disable-validation`

Comment: @johndoe Yes, but finishing the disabling requires physical access.

Comment: I forgot about the verification after reboot when you run those commands.

Answer (score 0):

- Set bios passphrase
- Encrypt your hard drive and store the key somewhere else
- Disable default ssh
- Disable default RDP
- Set strict Firewall rules

As much as I know, no one yet was able to crack or bypass Windows Bitlocker. For Ubuntu, if it is high configured it will be super hard to break through , Else, everything still possible...